# Deleting the proper CCSprite from an array in a schedule

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Before I explain my issue, I made this very not neat illustration of how my project works - 
[image: dont cringe at the colors its a neat font]

My issue is - when the time that I want to check damage is up, I want to delete that object from the array! I have tried deleting it in the checkForDamage, but as this gets called with `ccTime`it just deletes every object (when I use `removeObjectAtIndex:0` to get rid of the first one). I can't put it in the `stopCheckDamage`because while the damage on the first one is being checked, the player might as well have put another bomb down.

The `checkForDamage`works just fine when the user gets hit, I `break;` it and calls stopCheckDamage. My problem is when the user does NOT get hit, because then the nonexisting sprite stays in the array and just messes stuff up. I have been thinking about every way I know of and I can't seem to find a way to delete a specific object after three seconds delay if the player doesn't get hit.

**I also made a pastebin for the relevant code, which you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/6mJnQJ8Y)**

Comment: Aw 4 views my terrible picture scared everyone away :(

Comment: ah, you hid the code, well done. ;)
I see lots and lots of duplication in there, any chance you could clean that up first? And the formatting too.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Improved the code, probably possible to make it even more efficient but atleast got rid of the if-blocks that probably made you cringe. http://pastebin.com/6mJnQJ8Y

Comment: Somewhat solved it (I think), take a look @ http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/26664/is-this-proper-code-for-removing-a-ccsprite-under-certain-conditions

Answer (score 1):

This is just an idea,

You have an array of all of the objects. You just need to know which one to delete.
So, why not give each object a `tag` that gets added into the array. When you go to delete that object test its tag and delete it.

```
//Say your array has 10  objects in it, 
//There will be 10 objects each with a tag 1-10.
//When you want to delete an object,
```

**EDIT**

```
//Before you add each object to the array, use a `for` loop

for (int i = 0; i < theMaxNumberOfTagsYouWant; i++)

{
self.myObject.tag = i;
[self.myArray addObject:self.myObject];
//This will loop thru as many times as you want, specify using the 
//maxNumberOfTagsYouWant variable. and it will give it a tag, which'll be the value of `i` 
//which gets increased for each object you insert into the array, Then when you want to     
//remove the object, use the below code to remove the object using it's tag.
}

-(void)deleteObjectFromArray{
[self.myArray removeObjectAtIndex:myObject.tag];
}
```

Hope this helps a bit. :)

Comment: I thought about using tags, but I have not been able to come up with a way.

Comment: I can not find a way to apply this to my code. Did you read the code sample I posted? See if you can find a way to implement it into that if possible!:)